# Redirecting old urls to new urls in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

After publishing site in Django, I changed my slugs and now old pages show as errors in Google search. Is there a way to automatically redirect them without having to write an individual redirect for each page?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things you need to do to make sure that your website gets crawled properly.

In regards to the redirection, you can use `django.http.HttpResponsePermanentRedirect` to perform the redirection. Just keep the view, and when a user navigates to this view, redirect them to the proper URL.

You should also create a sitemap, which lists out all of the URLs for your website. You can then submit this sitemap to google using their [webmaster tool](https://developers.google.com/search) if you have not already done so. This will inform their crawler of all the pages that they need to crawl without worrying on them missing some information

Comment: All that is done except for django.http.HttpResponsePermanentRedirect.

How can I apply it? DO you I have to include it as part of a function/view?

Comment: You should keep the old views and redirect user requests to the old addresses, to the new addresses. For this you should use django.http.HttpResponsePermanentRedirect(new_url) .This is a principled and professional thing that you can do

Comment: Watch this https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301